# How to measure trajectory regularity?

Tags: kinematics, experimental-technique, algorithms

I have two animal running trajectories. A regular one with repeated back and forth running between point A and B, like the one on top in the figure. The other one is very irregular, animal paused and turned around a lot in the middle.  Is there any algorithm to measure the regularity of a trajectory, like repeated activity on the top?  And compare the extend of regularity between the two trajectories?  By 'more regular trajectory', I mean animal run with higher mean speed, less turn back and less pauses in the middle, more laps within the same amount of time. The figure above is for demonstration purpose, since animal can not run straight with constant speed anyway. 
[image]

Comment: Do you only have the trajectory or also the velocity at each point on the trajectory?

Comment: I do have velocity at each point.

Comment: In that case you could calculate the standard deviation  of the absolute speed. A more regular path will have a less wide speed distribution. This is not a perfect measure for regularity however, just an indicator.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about strategies / procedures for measuring animal movements.

Comment: @BrandonEnright: Right, this belongs more to Computational Science.

Comment: I am flabbergasted that "measuring movement" is not somehow considered "not physics." Jeez, guys!

Comment: See [fractal dimension](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/dimension.shtml). The top one has $f \approx 1$ and the the bottom one $f>1$.

Comment: This is a [Math.SE] problem. Measure the total length with different length yardsticks and you will get a more pronounced effect with the irregular pattern. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_dimension

Comment: @ja72 I guess what you suggested is more applicable in 2-D situations or measure regularity of polygons. In my case, the trajectory is linear, measuring some sort of displacement may be easier. Thanks.

Comment: This is an underspecified problem that cannot be objectively answered. You can look at fractal dimension, total path length, distributions of velocities, correlations between directions on some scale, or three dozen other metrics. My advice: step back, take a deep breath, and think about what you really want to measure about the system. Maybe you're interested in energetics, or cognitive simplicity, or emergent behavior, or obstacle pathing. It all depends.

Comment: This is more of a math problem math, but you could also consider doing a fourier analysis; look for the periodicity and relative strength of each periodic mode. A more regular (back and forth) path would be more periodic I would think. At least in speed or position.

Comment: @Jim I assume you meant taking fourier transform of speed and plot against position?

Comment: @sgyf not necessarily. If I were really interested, I'd put speed and position in as functions of time and plot everything. Fourier decomposition, transforms, the derivatives... everything

Comment: Hi @sgyf. I'm temporary(?) putting this on-hold because 4 users had already voted to migrate it to Math.SE, where the question would seem even more out of place than here. After all, the question is about a physical measurement in an experimental setup.

Comment: @Jim I guess that would be spectrogram kind of plot. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If it were me, I would take the velocity as a function of time, and split into constant segments.  For real data you will likely have to determine a threshold for what constant means, but in either case, split the trajectory up into "constant" velocity segments.  Then compute distance traveled in each of these segments.  Looking at the histogram of distances from a path, you should be able to characterize its "regularity".  Animals tend to have power law distributed length segments, also known as [levy flight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levy_flight), whereas a completely regular path would have only a few distances making up its segments.